# Problem with desktop screen after upgrade

Tags: directory, home-directory

After doing a software upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.94 now when PC boots the contents of my home screen are displayed on the desktop. Any ideas how to stop this please ???

Comment: Are these content still seen in the `home` directory?

Comment: Yes still in home directory

Comment: Then if this is the case just delete them and restart your computer and lets see if it re-appears.

Comment: Can not do that as these folders are required ! Folders like download, documents, music, hp printer driver etc.

Comment: if the folders there are the same in `/home/username` then why can't you remove them. The system should use those in `/home/username` not those in `~/Desktop`!

Comment: When I try to remove them the same files are also removed in the home folder. It seems home folder contents are displayed on desktop as well as home folder.

Comment: Then its best to leave them for now while a solution is sort...